# Make an existing web application portable & run from IIS Express on USB

Tags: .net, silverlight, web-applications, sql-server-ce, iis-express

I am very new to using IIS express (have worked previously with standard IIS), I am trying to get an existing web application that runs via IIS on a web server using the application pool.

The set up of the existing server is that it uses one application pool which loads two applications appname appnameCore With a physical path like

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\appname\applications\appname C:\inetpub\wwwroot\appname\applications\appnameCore

It is a Silverlight based application.

Currently the application uses an MS SQL database but I would like to change this to MS SQL CE I am not quite sure how to set up the same sort of environment, at the moment I have the web server running from a pen stick (memory stick/drive) and I would like to make the application portable. IIS Express is running from the Pen Drive fine at the moment but I am not sure how to configure the app pools.

I think I am also right in saying MS SQL CE uses .sdf instead of .mdf for databases, how can I make an existing .mdf database into the right format?

I have seen another article where someone has made another web application run from USB using the database on there as well http://leekelleher.com/2011/01/15/umbraco-on-usb-usin-iis-express-and-sqlce4/

I think it is possible but I have have got stuck with the how to after trying for quite some time.

I would really appreciate any help you can give me.

If I can give any more information or expand the question in some way please let me know.

Thanks, Glenn :)

Comment: the conversion from mdf to sdf format was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453123/converting-mdf-to-sdf regards,