# Converting MDF to SDF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, mdf, sdf

I've done a bit of Googling trying to find out how to convert a `.MDF` file to a `.SDF`. There doesn't seem to be much around apart from an old article for something called 'SQL Server to SQL Server Compact Edition Database Copy Utility'. As this is so old, I doubt it will work with the newer versions of SQL Server databases. Is there a more established and official method of achieving this now? Ideally I need something that will migrate the data as well as the table structures.

Comment: Since the full SQL Server (with the `.mdf` file) has a lot more features, data types etc., this could be rather tricky to handle generically. Also, since Microsoft has more or less deprecated SQL Server **CE** (with the `.sdf` files), I doubt there's going to be a lot of development in that area......

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was heading for depreciation, so thanks for the heads up! Will re-think the original reasons to selecting this option now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use my free VS add-in "SQL Server Compact Toolbox" to migrate data and schema from a SQL Server database to SQL Server Compact via script or directly in the GUI

Comment: Please let me know if you encounter any issues!